# Coordinate system in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, c++11, stdvector

Hi I would like to make a coordinate system using c++. I will be getting a few (x,y) coordinates from the user and using it I need to make a coordinate system(more of a map) style. How can I achieve this? It needs to look like the diagram below. Should I use a 2D array or vector and how to make the loop do the marking differently?

(2,0)(4,3)(7,8)
Needs to look like

```
 **1************
 ***************
 ***************
 ***************
 ***1***********
 ***************
 ***************
 ********1******
```

This is the code I got so far, but the problem is I can't mark more than one coordinate in it. I just used 2 for loops to do it

```
for(int i = -6; i < 7; i++) 
    if (i < 0) 
        cout<<" "<<i; 
    else 
        cout<<"  "<<i; 
cout<<endl; 

for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++) 
    { 
        cout<<(char)(i + 49); 
        for(int j = -6; j < 7; j++) 
        if(i == y - 1 && j == x) 
            cout<<" x "; 
        else 
            cout<<" . "; 

        cout<<(char)(i + 49)<<endl; 
    }
```

Please advise. Thanks !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would advice you to use either `vector<string>` or `vector<vector<char> >`  or even `vector<vector<string> >` depending on what do you intend to store in a cell. If a cell is a single character then probably the first option is the best. 
And after that creating the map is really easy:

```
int n,m;
cin >> n >> m;
vector<string> a(n, string(m, '*');
```

I am not sure what are the '.' and 'x'  in the code above but I imaging all that is left for you is to input several pairs of coordinates and replace the respective element in the `vector<string>` with '1'.

Hope this helps.

Comment: vector<vector<char>> ftw. makes marking the elements intuitive imho. +1, btw. But your right, for dumping to the console its hard to beat a big stack of strings =P

Comment: Accelerated C++ (Koenig & Moo) use the vector-of-string approach here too. It allows an `a[y][x]` syntax. This may be counter-intuitive.

Comment: +1, this is probably the path of least resistance for the op. But it might be worth noting that depending on how sparse the 'points of interest' are relative to map size, and *if the map needs to dynamically grow or not*, defining a CoordType wrapping std::pair and with appropriate comparison operator, and using it as a key in a map/set (similar to Pawel's answer) might be a more natural implementation. IMO, whether the grid map's dimensions are constant over its lifetime is a key determining factor between which approach works better.

Answer (score 1):

I would advice using `std::set` of `std::pair` instead of `std::vector` - there is no need to keep whole grid in memory, we just need points.

http://liveworkspace.org/code/f434521b804485f16786556762780448

Comment: Whaaaat?  Oh, you mean a container that holds the magic points rather than holding the whole grid.  I get it

Comment: The `map` of `map` is a terrible idea, because that's just going to be significantly larger and slower than a vector.  In no way is it better.  The `set` of special points is a good idea through.

Comment: Slower - yes, larger - maybe, but I doubt it. It's only possible if number of magic points will be significant (like 10%-20% of whole points on grid). Using `vector` to hold whole grid is probably little more than 225B - I think `map` with 15 points will be still smaller than that.

Comment: Check again, in your demo you put _every_ point into the map of maps.

Comment: Where? I put 3 points, so 3 maps with 1-element maps will be created.

Comment: As shown in [This demo](http://liveworkspace.org/code/94e6c45ba8c013caae009df295170a9a) your outer map contains 13 inner maps, and the inner maps contain 15 elements.  It's fixable, but would be more code.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. I forgot I check for existence with `operator[]` not `find`.

Comment: This is little less convenient than `map` in `map`, but still quite readale (kind of...) - http://liveworkspace.org/code/7bcde07d293de932e7f957581a94dee0

Answer (score 0):

To answer your other problem, you could use a loop to make the changes and another to show your result.
Using izomorphius's suggestion, it would look like this if you use a list to store pairs of coordinates:

```
vector<string> matrix ;
list<pair> PairList ;

for (list<pair>::const_iterator it = PairList.beguin(); i < PairList.end(); it++) {
    matrix[ (*it).second ][ (*it).first ] = "." ;
}
```

And to show the result:

```
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.size; i++) {
    cout << matrix[i] << endl ;
}
```